# Does anyone know how to create this component in React native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a component as seen in the image attached. The circle is a progress bar and the blue colour is the progress, I could use a circular progress bar component for that but I'm not sure how can I show dates as seen in the image, the text in blue will be the current date. If anyone knows how to do this please help.

[image]

Edit: I want to add the date to the progress bar, I have found the circular progress bar component.

Comment: Will this be any help? https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/tirthasourav/circular-date-selector, this is done using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#circle

Comment: @dejavu-reilzk I have edited my question, I want to add the date to the progress bar, I have found the circular progress bar component.

Comment: @souravdey I will check out the package.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Circular Progress](https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress)

**Usage**

```
import { AnimatedCircularProgress } from 'react-native-circular-progress';

<AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={120}
  width={15}
  fill={100}
  tintColor="#00e0ff"
  onAnimationComplete={() => console.log('onAnimationComplete')}
  backgroundColor="#3d5875" />
```

You can also define a function that'll receive current progress and for example display it inside the circle:

```
<AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={200}
  width={3}
  fill={this.state.fill}
  tintColor="#00e0ff"
  backgroundColor="#3d5875">
  {
    (fill) => (
      <Text>
        { this.state.fill }
      </Text>
    )
  }
</AnimatedCircularProgress>
```

You can also define a function that'll receive the location at the top of the progress circle and render a custom SVG element:

```
<AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={120}
  width={15}
  fill={100}
  tintColor="#00e0ff"
  backgroundColor="#3d5875"
  padding={10}
  renderCap={({ center }) => <Circle cx={center.x} cy={center.y} r="10" fill="blue" />}
  />
```

Finally, you can manually trigger a duration-based timing animation by putting a ref on the component and calling the `animate(toValue, duration, easing)` function like so:

```
<AnimatedCircularProgress
  ref={(ref) => this.circularProgress = ref}
  ...
/>

this.circularProgress.animate(100, 8000, Easing.quad); // Will fill the progress bar linearly in 8 seconds
```

The `animate-function` returns the timing animation so you can chain, run in parallel etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what you are looking for...
https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts
It is ProgressCircle. hope help You...

Comment: I have edited my question, I want to add the date to the progress bar, I have found the circular progress bar component.